# How to set the selected item of UITabBar by code

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller linking 3 view controllers. On controller A, I have a button linking to controller C. But when I use segue or `presentViewController:animated:completion:` it will show controller C but won't update the tab bar item. Is there a way to make it update by code so the user won't have to press it to get it to work properly. Thanks.

Comment: How about `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2]`?

Comment: @Leo Works, you can add it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setSelectedIndex` of `UITabBarController`

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2]
```